# Angular 2 Input ID not getting bound to element

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an Angular 2 component that gets elementId as an Input then sets that as an id attribute on a div. For some reason the div's id not getting set.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-chart',
    template: `
        <div>
           Hello {{elementId}}
           <div [id]="elementId"></div>
        </div>
    `
})

export class MyChartComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() elementId: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.createChart();
    }

    createChart() {
        console.log("ID: ", this.elementId);
        ...
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like in the parent component:

```
<div *ngFor="let chart of charts">
    <my-chart [elementId]="chart.id"></my-chart>
</div>
```

--

When I inspect element on the div, it shows that the id attribute was not set on the HTML element. Also the Hello {{elementId}} only shows the "Hello ". There is no elementId filled in. See photo below.

But the `console.log` statement correctly prints out the id, indicating that the input binding is correct.

Image: [Inspect Element shows id is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEsbg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular lifecycle AfterViewInit is where the place all the html and js binding happened.

You should write external dom monuplation in your `AfterViewInit` method.

```
export class MyChartComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
    @Input() elementId: string;

    ngOnInit() {

    }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        console.log("ID: ", this.elementId);
        Plotly.newPlot(this.elementId, ...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but this also didn't work. I don't think the problem is related to the timing of the call. The problem is that the div's id isn't getting set. No longer how long I wait, the id still isn't set. The console.log in ngOnInit() shows that this.elementId **does** exist and is bound correctly.

Comment: hmm, that is what i got. lets see if we get more answers

Comment: Hi Aniruddha, I've edited the question a little more to be clear! Thanks

Comment: After like an hour, this solution suddenly started working! Not sure why it didn't work initially.

Answer (score 1):

there is a equivalent for `document.getElementById();` in angular and you can use that.

you can use element reference (ElementRef) in angular and querySelector the way you used in jQuery.

```
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  // this is inside any of the method
  // this is to select multiple 
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.mandate');

  // this is to select single
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.mandate')
```

So rather using document, you should use `ElementRef`

Comment: The library I'm using uses document.getElementById, so I have no choice on that matter. That's why I have to ensure the div's id attribute is set correctly. I've edited my question to make that more clear.

Comment: added another answer